# Account/ Opportunity sharing

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Is there a way to add "Account Access" option under the "Opportunity Access" option (like it is shown in Account sharing) without creating a custom VF page and just by playing around with the sharing settings on the individual Opportunity sharing page?


 [image]

Comment: [Salesforce SE](https://https://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask questions that are very SF-specific

Comment: Ah! That was so silly of me. I usually post it there. Not sure how did i miss it.